# Family visit visa from Pakistan with 4 large credits in bank statement. How to justify?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

We are applying for a family visit visa for my parents. While me and my brother stay here our parents want to attend the post graduation ceremony of our sister who is a British citizen now.

We are providing 6 month bank statements:

- It receives a regular pension of 226 gbp.
- The new job of my father started in August so there are only 2 salary inflows of 612 gbp.
- We transferred 7500 gbp from a savings account to the current account at the end of May 2018, because we knew we had to apply for a visa with the current account statement (the balance was quite low at the time).
- In september we had a sale of property. This led to 16000 gbp into the account, but was of course not for the visa purpose. We are gathering funds to purchase a new home in our own country.

How to justify to the UK government that this sale is not for visa purposes, and how to explain the transfer from the savings account?

The savings account has a balance of 16000 gbp after the transfer to the current account.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE! Glad you did some initial research for this question. Two questions: 1) Do you have statements for your savings account which show you saved up money over a long  period, and 2) Do you have any documentation proving you sold the property at the stated amount?

Comment: Yes we have saving account from 2014 when father retired. it shows the transation and also the proof of source of funds in saving account we have. secondly the sale deed all translated and verified by government is there. yes the evidence is there.

Comment: Money parking is not well seen by visa officials. So you may show the origin of such money (it is ok to show the transfer of money from saving account (but it was OK [or better] just to show that you have various bank accounts). You may show some document about save of property.  In general, if you are doubts, the immigration officials will have them also, so try to explain it on visa application, as you did here. Do not assume they will understand/trust you (they will have much less information, and possibly other culture)

Comment: Are there any difficulties for you to submit your saving accounts statement alongside with your current account statement?

Comment: I believe you've got the transfer from savings account bit covered - you don't really need to explain it is 'for visa' as long as you show them the saving accounts statement. Unfortunately I don't really have an answer for the other part of the question (how to show the property sale is not for visa purpose) - it will be your job to convince immigration officials that your parents do not intend to go underground, and the selling of the property is actually doing against your parents' favour. Perhaps you will need evidence of your parents in a process of purchasing the new home.

Comment: The comment thread requires a cleanup, and key points included into the question - I can do so tonight, but if some nice soul can do it beforehand I will of course be grateful.

Comment: By "current account", do you mean checking/chequing account? I think this is a British specific term, so you might want to edit your question to be more clear to Americans. I think most Americans would interpret "current account" as "the account I currently have". "we knew we had to apply for a visa with the current account statement" Are you saying that you believe that your savings account would not be taken into consideration? What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2):

This is really simple. You need to provide good reliable documents that back up what you say about the money transfers. For example:

- To prove that you transferred 7500 GBP from your savings accounts, provide statements from the savings accounts. This will not only confirm the transfer is what you say, but give a much better picture of your finances.
- To prove that the 16000 GBP came from sale of a property, provide documents showing that you did in fact sell a property, and it was for 16000 GBP

The transfer of 7500 GBP almost certainly hurt you because it looks like what we call 'funds parking'. You will have to work extra hard in future applications (meaning provide extremely good documentation) to overcome the suspicion that you have been doing this. The best way to do this would have been to not transfer the money out of the savings account, but just to provide statements from the savings account to show that you have the money.

Selling the property was also a bad move. Not only does it look like you were trying to inflate your funds available, owning property would have provided you with ties to your home country, and increased the likelihood that you were accepted. Selling property makes it look like you are preparing to leave the country. If time and circumstances permit, using the funds from the sale to buy the new home you are wanting would both remove the problem of the 16000GBP and give you additional ties to your home country.

Comment: @Warda123 To repeat what I said in the answer, there is no problem as long as you also provide statements for the savings accounts that you transferred the money out of. In fact it was unnecessary to transfer money out of the savings account. Just provide the statement from the savings account to show that you have the funds.